# Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string

Tags: errors, wp-error

After deleting some categories (shouldn't have done this), I get the following error

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted
>   to string in [FILENAME] on line 45

Here's the file which caused the error. Here's an excerpt (line 45 is `$output .= '<a href="' . $link  . '">' . $term->name. '</a>, ';`)

```
   ...
  foreach($item['value'] as $value) {
        $term = get_term($value, $fieldSettings['taxonomy']);
        $link = get_term_link($term);

        // no option may inerrupt !
        if(!$term) {
          continue;
        }

        if(isset($formatterSettings['link_bool']) && $formatterSettings['link_bool']) {
          $output .= '<a href="' . $link  . '">' . $term->name. '</a>, ';
        } else {
          $output .= $term->name . ', ';
        }
      }
    }
 ...
```

How can I fix this problem? I recreated all the deleted categories (I backuped their names and slugs), but the error still remains.

Thank you for your help!

Here's the complete file

```
namespace Hydra\Formatters;

use Hydra\Builder;

class TaxonomyFormatter extends BasicFormatter {

  public function __construct() {
    $this->name = 'taxonomy';
  }

  public function render(\HydraFieldViewRecord $viewView, $post) {

    $items = $this->getValues($viewView);
    if(!$items) {
      return $items;
    }

    $fieldSettings = $viewView->field->attributes;
    $formatterSettings = $viewView->settings;

    $meta = $viewView->field->meta;
    $output = '';


    foreach ($items as $item) {
      if(is_string($item['value'])) {
        if($item['value'] == 0) {
          continue;
        }
        $item['value'] = array($item['value']);
      }

      foreach($item['value'] as $value) {
        $term = get_term($value, $fieldSettings['taxonomy']);
        $link = get_term_link($term);

        // no option may inerrupt !
        if(!$term) {
          continue;
        }

        if(isset($formatterSettings['link_bool']) && $formatterSettings['link_bool']) {
          $output .= '<a href="' . $link  . '">' . $term->name. '</a>, ';
        } else {
          $output .= $term->name . ', ';
        }
      }
    }

    $output = trim($output, ', ');
    $terms = $output;

    $output = '';
    $output .= '<div ' . $this->printAttributes($viewView) . '>';

    if ($meta->prefix) {
      $output .= "<div class=\"field-prefix\" >" . $meta->prefix . "</div>";
    }

    $output .= "<div class=field-value>" . $terms . "</div>";
    if ($meta->suffix) {
      $output .= "<div class=\"field-suffix\">" . $meta->suffix . "</div>";
    }
    $output .= "</div>";

    return $output;
  }

  public function getSettingsForm($parentElement) {
    parent::getSettingsForm($parentElement);
    $parentElement->addField('checkbox', array('link_bool', __('Link to taxonomy page', 'hydraforms')))
      ->setDefaultValue(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`get_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term#Return_Values) can return a [`WP_Error`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) object in addition to a falsy value for term not found or an actual term row.

You fix this, by adding an additional check:

```
if (!$term) {
   continue;
}
```

Becomes:

```
if (!$term || is_wp_error($term)) {
    continue;
}
```

You should also do this above the `get_term_link` call.

```
$term = get_term($value, $fieldSettings['taxonomy']);
if (!$term || is_wp_error($term)) {
    continue;
}

$link = get_term_link($term);
```

`get_term` usually returns a `WP_Error` when the taxonomy doesn't exist or isn't registered (you can [look at the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L940) for more info). So much sure that it is. If you *are* registering it, make sure that the above code (that's causing the error) is happening sometime after `init`, where the taxonomy is probably registered.